# Dynamic dependency injection in Angular ui-router resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Is there any way to make dependency injection inside ui-router resolve function?

I trying to achieve something like this:

```
resolve : {
    anArray : function(/* no dependencies yet */) {
        var currency = 'eur';

        //here I'd like to make a dependency injection
        var currencyDetail = /*injected dependency*/.get();
        return currencyDetail;
    }
}
```

In the original project I have a large array at `currency` and a long list of services like `eurdata`, `usddata` etc, many of them not always used in resolving `anArray`.

Tried `$injector.get(currency + 'data')` but not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have $injector inject inside resolve function and ask for dependency to it

```
resolve : {
    anArray : ['$injector', function($injector) {
        var currency = 'eur';

        //here I'd like to make a dependency injection
        var currencyDetail = $injector.get(dependencyName);
        return currencyDetail;
    }]
}
```

Comment: Yep. I forgot to inject the $injector. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the usual array-notation:

```
resolve: {
  anArray: ['dependency', function(dependency) {
    var currency = 'eur';

     //here I'd like to make a dependency injection
     dependency.doSomething();

    var currencyDetail = /*injected dependency*/.get();
    return currencyDetail;
  }]
}
```

Comment: As I see, you directly injecting a dependency called `dependency`, but in my case I don't have any dependencies at that point. I want to inject them inside the function.

Comment: So, at what point would you have them? Do you dynamically create services? Are you loading them from a backend?

Comment: I have all the services created, but I don't want to inject all of them, just a fraction, based on `currency`.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then you could use Pankaj's answer. But bear in mind, that it wouldn't be minification safe. Use the array-notation to ensure minification safety.

Comment: @PankajParkar, yeah. I either missed it, or you edited your answer. Anyways, it's correct now

Comment: @JanS earlier It wasn't have that DI inline array.. I made edit as looked into your comment.. Thanks :-)